# How to query an array and retrieve it from MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

Updated:

I have a document on the database that looks like this:

[image]

My question is the following:

How can I retrieve the first 10 elements from the `friendsArray` from database and sort it descending or ascending based on the `lastTimestamp` value.

I don't want to download all values to my API and then sort them in Python because that is wasting my resources.

I have tried it using this code (Python):

```
listOfUsers = db.user_relations.find_one({'userId': '123'}, {'friendsArray' : {'$orderBy': {'lastTimestamp': 1}}}).limit(10)
```

but it just gives me this error `pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Unknown expression $orderBy`

Any answer at this point would be really helpful! Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use aggregate
first `unwind`

then `sort` according timestap
`group` by _id  to create sorted array
use `addfields` and `filter` for getting first 10 item of array

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match:{userId:"123"}},
  {
    "$unwind": "$friendsArray"
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "friendsArray.lastTimeStamp": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      friendsArray: {
        $push: "$friendsArray"
      }
    },
    
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      friendsArray: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$friendsArray",
          as: "z",
          cond: {
            $lt: [
              {
                $indexOfArray: [
                  "$friendsArray",
                  "$$z"
                ]
              },
              10
            ]
          }// 10 is n first item
          
        }
      }
    },
    
  }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/2Usk5sRY2L2

and for pagination use this

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match:{userId:"123"}},
  {
    "$unwind": "$friendsArray"
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "friendsArray.lastTimeStamp": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      friendsArray: {
        $push: "$friendsArray"
      }
    },
    
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      friendsArray: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$friendsArray",
          as: "z",
          cond: {
            $and: [
              {
                $gt: [
                  {
                    $indexOfArray: [
                      "$friendsArray",
                      "$$z"
                    ]
                  },
                  10
                ]
              },
              {
                $lt: [
                  {
                    $indexOfArray: [
                      "$friendsArray",
                      "$$z"
                    ]
                  },
                  20
                ]
              },
              
            ]
          }// 10 is n first item
          
        }
      }
    },
    
  }
])
```

Comment: Thank You Mohammad soo much man, you saved me so much headache. Do you know if is there a way to paginate this: i.e. how can I get the next 10 items (10-20)?

Comment: im update my answer but mongoplayground not worked for me and didn't check

Comment: Thanks man, but I have just one more question. Is there a way that I can instead of using _id: "$_id" use "userId" : "123" since I will not be able to access the _id? Also, when I try to run it to in flask, it gives me this response "<pymongo.command_cursor.CommandCursor object at 0x11a7fd670>" Thank you sooo much!!!

Comment: you want to do this for specific query , for example you want this pagination only for user =123 ?

Comment: Exactly, I want to do it for one document

Comment: I update my answer and add `$match` stage, now it will be for only docs or doc that have userId of 123

Answer (score 1):

The translation of your find to aggregation(we need unwind that why aggregation is used) would be like the bellow query.

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/amKz9gpQIQh)

Query  (for descending replace 1 with -1)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "userId": "123"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": {
      "path": "$friendsArray"
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "friendsArray.lastTimeStamp": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$limit": 10
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$friendsArray"
    }
  }
])
```

If you want to skip some before limit add one stage also

```js
{
  "$skip" : 10
}
```

To take the 10-20 messages for example.

Comment: Thank You for your answer, but I have one question, what is the difference between yours and Mohammed's answer? Your's is simpler and why is that? Is your code more efficient i.e. faster? I am really confused? :)

Comment: Mohammed's answer is the way to go if you want the 10 messages for all users, you want only for 1 user so you dont need the group. (mohammed wrote it for all users and then realized i think that you want only 1 user), also i think that Mohammed should use `$slice` on that array for example 10 to 20 not filter (that filter is slower and if duplicates in the array i think it doesnt work). If you want to use it for all users, use mohammad soulution and replace the last part with `$slice` at least i think this is the right way.

Comment: Ok, thank You for the answer and the explanation!! I will then use your answer!

Comment: I have just remembered, I have one small question. Is there a way that I can also add an argument to the query above so that I can only get objects for the friendsArray where the "message" is empty i.e. messages = ""? Thank You

Comment: no i think mohammed solution with filter works even if duplicates, but `$slice` would be faster and simpler, i think its safe to use, but its written for all users its more general, and bigger a bit.

Comment: yes you can if you want only the empty messages add after the unwind a match stage, 
see example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-ZfpsWyW5u5)

Comment: I don't think I have explained what I want really good. In the picture above, you can see that there is a field after lastTimestamp that is called message. Can I only get objects that have that field equal to Empty String. So the message field would be equal to "".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236858/discussion-between-takis-and-bilal-drndo).

Comment: Thank You, yeah that worked perfectly! I have sent the last comment before I saw your answer! Thank You man soo much! It worked flawlessly!

Comment: no worries you asked simple things, mongodb documentation is very nice and simple check it if you need help, it has examples also

Comment: I know I am getting quite repetitive, but really this is the last question that I have :(. Is there a way that I can get data from other collection and add it to the friendsArray values. What I mean is the following. I have one collection named users where every document holds info about one user. That user has username and profilePictureUrl and userId. As you can see in the updated picture above, there is a new field called userId and it holds a value. Now is there a way that in the query above I can retrieve username and pictureUrl based on the userId and get all of that data in an array?

Comment: looks like `$lookup` create a new question and  if you can and give the users collection also, if you can give your data in JSON not images. [JSON beautifier](https://jsonformatter.org/json-pretty-print)

Comment: I have made another question: The link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69093371/how-to-merge-data-from-two-collections-in-mongodb