# How to merge data from two collections in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I really need help with my current problem.

The Problem: How can I merge data from two collections?

The first collection is called `users` where every document holds info about one user. One example of a document in this collection in JSON Format:

```
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("userId1"),
        "nameAndSurname": "Name 1",
        "arrayOfImages": ["wwww.urlToImage1.jpeg"],
        "favouritePlayer" : "Monfils",
        "sport" : "Tennis",
        "isProfileBlocked" : false
    }
```

The second collection is called `user_relations` where every document holds info about friends that a certain user from `users` collection have. One example of a document in this collection in JSON Format:

```
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("someRandomString"),
        "userId": "userId1",
        "friendsArray": [
        {
            "userId" : "userId2",
            "lastTimestamp": 19236752642,
            "message": "Hellooo"
        },
        {
            "userId" : "userId3",
            "lastTimestamp": 12236752342,
            "message": "Yeah",
        },
        ]
    }
```

I have a Python query that looks like this:

```
db.user_relations.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "userId": "userId1"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": {
      "path": "$friendsArray"
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "friendsArray.lastTimestamp": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$limit": 10
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$friendsArray"
    }
  }
])
```

and the response when I run that query looks like this:

```
[{'userId': 'userId2', 'lastTimetamp': 19236752642, 'message': 'Yeah'}, {'userId': 'userId3', 'lastTimestamp': 12236752342, 'message': 'Hellooo'}]
```

Now what I want to do is modify this query so that I can get `nameAndSurname` and `arrayOfImages[0]` values from `users` collection for each value i.e. user in the `friendsArray` so that the response could be:

```
[{'userId': 'userId2', 'nameAndSurname : 'Name 2', 'pictureUrl' : 'wwww.urlToImage2.jpeg', 'lastTimestamp': 19236752642, 'message': 'Yeah'}, {'userId': 'userId3', 'nameAndSurname : 'Name 3', 'pictureUrl' : 'wwww.urlToImage3.jpeg', 'lastTimestamp': 12236752342, 'message': 'Hellooo'}]
```

Thank You for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Y_kpqxJgx_q)

You want a `$lookup` but you want is like SQL like join, all fields in the root document so an unwind and replace root is added to merge in 1 document.

Query

```js
db.user_relations.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$eq": [
          "$userId",
          "userId1"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": {
      "path": "$friendsArray"
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "friendsArray.lastTimeStamp": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$limit": 10
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$friendsArray"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "users",
      "localField": "userId",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "joined__"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": {
      "path": "$joined__"
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          "$joined__",
          "$$ROOT"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "joined__": 0
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thank You @Takis for real for taking the time and answering my questions. You are a real life saver for me since I really needed to transfer some data to MongoDB. I have updated the question and you can see now that there is a isProfileBlocked field in the users collection. Is there any way that I can specify that that field needs to be false and also how can I exclude certain fields like favouritePlayer and sport. I have tried using $project but it doesn't work.

Comment: see [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7Lypr5lsCQV) adds one filter and remove those 2 fields, we coudl filter those and remove those fields at the lookup up, if we used lookup with pipeline, but it would be small difference in perfomance so i guess you are fine with simppler query.

Comment: Yeah, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks you for your help! :)

Comment: Hey @Takis, I am having a little problem. My _id field is not a String but it's an ObjectId. When I try to run this query, it gives me error. I have researched on the Internet but I can not find a satisfying answer. Do You know how can I solve it. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: i don't know what can it be the problem, but we have 2 functions `$toObjectId` and `$toString` to allow us the convertion if the type is the problem. to make for example 
`"61448da8c1a2f7417cea0977" <-> ObjectId("61448da8c1a2f7417cea0977")` . I used strings because `ObjectId("userId1")` will cause error, ObjectId takes as argument only 1 hexadecimal string of length 24. If you want to use custom _ids maybe use simple numbers? Or use the driver to generate you ObjectId.

Comment: I have tried using $toObjectId and $toString but it tells me that foreignField or localField need to strings not dictionaries. Also, I added $addFields and tried to convert that way, but it still won't retrieve any documents. I have made a link, you can check it out here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/mWpTF2UhaSE. Thanks man

Comment: [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ukTlD9U5a3r) is ok? works like you wanted it to work? i added one stage to ` "$toObjectId": "$userId"` and also i fixed the lookup i think you did typing mistake, replaced `imgIdObjId` with `userId`

Comment: Yeah I noticed that, I have implemented it. I have one bonus question for you since You are clearly an expert when it comes to MongoDB and Aggregation. When using ChangeStreams, is there a way to observe for an insertion to an array. For example, when there is a new inserted Object to friendsArray ,can I get that Object specifically, not the whole array? I have already posted this question on Stack Overflow but nobody has given me a satisfying answer?

Comment: i dont know how to answer this, but you can check [this](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/) site also, its from MongoDB to help the users, i think you will get answer there, gl : )

Comment: Hey @Takis, I hope you are doing well. I would really appreciate if you could help me with my aggregation pipeline problem since it is really urgent and I would be really grateful if you could just give even a hint. The Link: friendsArray.lastMessage: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69742505/how-to-set-that-a-string-field-is-not-equal-to-empty-string-mongodb-aggregation