# How to set that a string field is not equal to empty string MongoDB aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

how do I set that a certain field can not be an empty string.
When I set `friendsArray.lastMessage` string field to be empty, it gives me results that I want i.e:

```
matches = db.user_relations.aggregate(
        [
            {"$match": {"userId": id}},
            {"$unwind": {"path": "$friendsArray"}},
            {"$sort": {"friendsArray.lastTimestamp": -1}},
            {"$match": {"friendsArray.lastMessage": ""}},
            {"$limit": 6},
            {"$replaceRoot": {"newRoot": "$friendsArray"}},
            {
                "$lookup": {
                    "from": "users",
                    "localField": "userId",
                    "foreignField": "_id",
                    "as": "joined__"
                }
            },
            {"$unwind": {"path": "$joined__"}},
            {"$replaceRoot": {"newRoot": {"$mergeObjects": ["$joined__","$$ROOT"]}}},
            {"$project": {"joined__": 0}},
            {"$match": {"$expr": {"$eq": ["$isProfileBlocked", False]}}},
            {
                '$addFields': {'userId': {'$toString': '$userId'}}
            },
            {"$unset": valuesToUnset}
        ]
    )
```

But when I change this: `{"$match": {"friendsArray.lastMessage": ""}},`
to this: `{"$match": {"friendsArray.lastMessage": {"$not" : [{"$eq": ""}]}}}`

it gives me some strange results? It mixes data and I really don't know what its doing?

I have tried putting `$ne` and `$nin` arguments and searched the whole internet, but I can not find a satisfying answer?

Does anybody know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: maybe give sample data and expected output, and find the stage that causes the problem, so we can test it

Answer (score 0):

You are not using a correct sintax on the `$eq` operator. Check the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/).

Note that the `$eq` in find is diferrent that the `$eq` in aggregations.

The correct way to do it is how you use it on this line:

```
{"$match": {"$expr": {"$eq": ["$isProfileBlocked", False]}}},
```

I also made an example of what you need [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MnT_1vXuU3i).